# Is it possible to understand the One Piece storyline by watching the movies only?

Tags: one-piece

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_One_Piece_films), there are 13 *One Piece* movies.

As a new viewer to the series (haven't watched the anime at all), is watching all the movies enough to understand the storyline, or are there some specific movies that can be enjoyed without knowing the *One Piece* universe?

Comment: Why are you watching them?  There are some that are (non-canon) retelling of previous arcs and may bring you up to speed on the story faster.  There is (unless I missed something) only one canon movie.  There are several completely non-canon ones which may or may not be worth watching (opinion).

Comment: Im with Kaine. There are a lot of details they just assume you know about the world as a whole. Powers unlocked and explained in the main series are just used in the movies without explanation, and many are complex, confusing, or vague even with the explanation. You dont want to feel lost, but that is going to happen when you watch a movie that uses stuff established sporadically over hundreds of episodes without watching those episodes. Its like watching any of the starwars movies except 4 or 1, and expecting to know whats going on.

Comment: @Ryan Eh.... that is a different message than what I said.  You aren't wrong though.  I have no idea which movies (if any) explain the basics of devil fruits and things like that.

Comment: @kaine I was more so adding on other details than expanding your point. I also see a Opinion based close vote here. I know SE can be harsh and this question does seem lacking so I can't completely disagree. Not wanting to watch a series simply because it has so many episodes is not a valid reason to skip to the movies that are derived from it. Asking about if you will be confused doing so is not a very factual question. Certainly, you could just accept the things you don't understand and get away with it (like accepting Luffy is stretchy), or not do so and be very confused.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow the story of *One Piece*, your only choice is either to watch the anime or to read the manga (you will complete it much faster since you can read a chapter in few minutes). Also a big bonus point for the manga is that there is no filler.

Regarding the movies, most of them are not-canon which means they don't fit in the story of *One Piece*. You can view them as a spin-off, which takes the existing characters and world setup but tells a totally different story that is in no way connected to the anime/manga.

So, in short, the only way to follow *One Piece* is either to read the manga or watch the anime.

Answer (score 1):

One Piece movies are extra mini-arcs beyond the original storyline. The movies have all the main characters and Oda (the author) has been involved with some of them, but they are not part of the main storyline.

If you want to understand the One Piece world, read the manga or watch the anime.